# Javascript promise not running the code in then()

Tags: javascript, animation, promise

I have an animation running that drops a pin at a certain point, then draws a path. Currently, when the pin drops, no path is drawn. This is because the function `next_code` is not being run

currently I have this:

```
function drawPath(source, desti, isUpper, first, last, arr) {
    var context;
    /*
     * Define context
     */
    //lower
    if (!isUpper) {
        var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
        context = c.getContext("2d");
        //upper
    } else {
        var cUpr = document.getElementById("myCanvasUpr");
        context = cUpr.getContext("2d");
    }

    context.lineCap = 'round';
    context.beginPath();

    /*
     * Get the coordinates from source and destination strings
     */
    var src = dict[source];
    var dst = dict[desti];

    /*
     * Get the point number of the point on the path that the source and destination connect to
     */

    var begin = point_num[source];
    var finish = point_num[desti];

    /*
     *   Marker
     */
    if (first) {
        var pause = true;
        var marker1 = new Image();
        return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
            marker1.onload = resolve;
            marker1.onerror = reject;
            marker1.src = "images/map_pin.png";
        }).then(function() {
            return animate_pin(marker1, context, point_coord[begin[0]])
        }).then(next_code);

    } else {
        context.fillStyle = 'green';
        context.beginPath();
        context.arc(point_coord[begin[0]][0], point_coord[begin[0]][1], 8, 0, 2 * Math.PI);

        context.strokeStyle = "green";
        context.stroke();
        context.fill();
    }
    var next_code = function() {
        console.log("In next_code");
        if (last) {
            /*var marker2 = new Image();
            marker2.onload = function(){
                marker2._x = point_coord[finish[0]][0]-15;
                marker2._y = point_coord[finish[0]][1]-22;
                context.drawImage(marker2, marker2._x, marker2._y,marker2.width,marker2.height);
            };
            marker2.src = "images/x_marks.png";*/
        } else {
            context.fillStyle = 'red';
            context.beginPath();
            context.arc(point_coord[finish[0]][0], point_coord[finish[0]][1], 6, 0, 2 * Math.PI);

            context.strokeStyle = "#ff0000";
            context.stroke();
            context.fill();
        }

        /*
         * Call the function that draws the entire path
         */
        draw_segments(begin, finish, src, dst, context, arr);
        //window.alert(JSON.stringify(vertices, null, 4))
        /*
         * Edit what the line looks like
         */
        context.lineWidth = 5;
        //context.strokeStyle = "#ff0000";
        //context.strokeStyle = "#ff3c3c";
        context.strokeStyle = "#f38f1d";
        context.stroke();
    }
}
```

And the animate function in question here is

```
function animate_pin(marker1, context, end){
    return new Promise(function(resolve) {
        var temp = end.slice(0);
        temp[0] = temp[0] - 1;
        temp[1] = temp[1] - 44;
        var start = temp.slice(0);
        start[0] = start[0] + 50;
        start[1] = start[1] - 50;
        var inc = 0.5;
        console.log(temp[0]);
        var runAnimation2 = function(){
            if(start[0] > temp[0]){
                console.log(start[0]);
                context.clearRect(0, 0, context.canvas.width, context.canvas.height);
                context.drawImage(document.getElementById('frame1'), 0, 0);
                start[0] = start[0] - inc;
                start[1] = start[1] + inc;
                marker1._x = start[0];
                marker1._y = start[1];
                context.drawImage(marker1, marker1._x, marker1._y,marker1.width,marker1.height);
                requestAnimationFrame(runAnimation2);
            } else {
                console.log("Hello");
                resolve();
            }
        };
        runAnimation2();
    });
}
```

Ultimately, I need `arr`  to be updated in `draw_segments`, and I need `animate_pin` to run and finish before `draw_segments` starts. I figured promises would be a good start, but there is when I ran into issues.

Is there a better way to get `animate_pin` to finish before `draw_segments` is run? If not, how can I get `draw_segments` to run with my current setup?

Note: `console.log` in the `animate_pin` function work as expected, but the `console.log` in the `next_code` function never runs

Comment: Apologies, SO doesnt like to keep my formatting when I hit `ctrl-k`. Arr is actually populated in `draw_segments`, I know its poor form to use globals in javascript but Im working on getting this functioning before optimizing in that way... at this point I should do it the other way around but Im already almost done! Anyway, about the returning a function, that is only because I wasnt sure how to trap the proper return value

Comment: `arr` is a global variable in the sheet. Values are calculated in `draw_segment` (not shown here) and then pushed using `arr.push(context,pre);`  Edit: Added my comment before your edit, sorry!

Comment: @JaromandaX I went ahead and added the original code before the promises, maybe itll show what the full intent is. But yeah, if those conditions arent met it should return an error, as those condition shouldnt be allowed (they are actually checked for before this function is ever entered, im not sure why they are checked again in here, that part isnt my code). Ill look at what you posted now!

Comment: @JaromandaX After putting in your code, I still have the same error. But I do think I understand how the promise works a little better now

Comment: @JaromandaX  I added a `console.log()` to see what the value of `Promise.resolve(arr)` was, but it is never reached? Right before the return... any idea?

Comment: @JaromandaX Ahh I see. I added a `console.log(arr)` before the `return arr` now, and still nothing is reported... Which confuses me, because shouldnt that line be reached?

Comment: Im confused, sorry.. I put a `console.log` before both returns and neither give me a result.. one of them, surely, should right?

Comment: You might want to work on accepting some answers here.  It appears you've accepted an answer on only 1 out of your last 9 questions.  Part of that has to do with how difficult it is to follow your questions and the code in some of them (that's on you to write clearer code and clearer questions).  Good, clear questions here usually get multiple good answers that the OP can then accept.

Comment: I've interacted with you on previous versions of this code in another question and my first reaction if I encountered this code in a project I was on would be to completely rewrite it to be far, far less complicated and simpler to follow.  Lots of bugs would probably disappear too and it would be a whole lot easier to get help too.

Comment: @JaromandaX - I'm talking about the other 7 of his previous questions that have no accepted answers.  One shouldn't be posting to stack overflow and accepting an answer on only 11% of the questions.  Either the questions are so bad they can't attract a decent answer or the OP just isn't following through on how they're supposed to use stack overflow.  I've personally decided to avoid this OP until they clean up their act here.  Complicated, obtuse code and questions with little follow through.  I personally would never invest in trying to "fix" this code.  Rewrite.

Comment: @JaromandaX Yeah, my guess is that the function that is calling `drawPath` is running before `drawPath` finishes due to the fact that we run some async functions... But i could be wrong. The main problem is I am not a web developer, so much of this is difficult for me to rewrite, otherwise I would have. Not to mention time constraints

Comment: @jfriend00 Many of those questions dont have answers that fixed the problem, hence why I havent accepted them. There are at least 2 that I need to accept however, I should probably go back and check some

Comment: @ChrisM - And, why do you think that is?  Good questions, get multiple good answers here.

Comment: @jfriend00 no answers do not always mean bad questions. There are often times when people who can answer he question simply do not look at it, or the answer is too difficult to get. I admit, not all of my questions are great

Comment: @JaromandaX regarding rewrite: I agree. Regarding the code: `drawPath` must be getting called because the animation in `animate_pin` runs, which confuses me as no `console.log` is working... maybe I have a typo? I am doing this: `var re = Promise.resolve(arr);
  console.log(re);` and `console.log(arr);`

Comment: With your batting average, this is not about the occasional good question that stumps people here.  This subject matter is not complex, any good Javascript programmer can participate in this subject - it's the code implementation that's complex and (in the case of the question I participated in), the clarity of the question and expression of the code relevant to that.  I strongly urge you to throw away this implementation and start over.  For starters, get rid of all global data.  Stop programming with side effects.  Put all state in an object.  Create methods that operate on that state.

Comment: @JaromandaX That was a typo from copy pasting segments of code, my mistake and good catch! I went ahead and just remove all global variables, and reposted the code. I am receiving the same issue

Comment: *"no globals"* ... apart from `dict`, `point_num`

Comment: @JaromandaX the`context = c.getContext("2d"); context = c.getContext("2d");` was a result of find/replace haha. Fixed that part. And those globals are basically a way for me to go from a string to its corresponding coordinate, I have around 400 points being used which are also global. 'no globals' referred to no globals that are changed, unless it is recommended to pass the dictionaries and points as parameters, but that seems long

Comment: @JaromandaX one interesting change: by removing globals I dont have to worry about the returns. The only problem is, the path is still not being drawn because `draw_segments` is not being reached. I will update my question to contain the current code again

Comment: @JaromandaX My thoughts too, but I dont see how it wouldnt (I suppose it could be reaching an error instead?) Edit: I placed a console.log inside the `else` that contains the `resolve()` and it came through, so at very least that `else` block and `resolve()` are being hit

Comment: @JaromandaX you guys have no faith in me haha, of course Ive done that! No surprise, it looks normal, which is why I dont see whats happening. I will update the animate code to at least contain one change ive made

Comment: @JaromandaX No it stops when its supposed to, and the log in the else is shown. Yes, Ive had a console.log in next_code, but it does not show

Comment: @JaromandaX Which is exactly why I am here... it doesnt make sense to me. I reposted the code with all `console.logs()` so you can see how I currently have it set up.. Maybe youll notice something I cannot

Comment: There has to be an issue with how the `animate_pin` function is returning the promise, how that return is being read, or how the function in `then` is being called...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the issue

Where `next_code` is used, it is `undefined` - because of variable hoisting, the var `next_code` is declaration is hoisted to the top of the function, but its definition is not - therefore it is `undefined`

because the `return new Promise` - the definition is never executed!

However, function definitions are hoisted - therefore, the code below will work

```
if (first) {
    var pause = true;
    var marker1 = new Image();
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        marker1.onload = resolve;
        marker1.onerror = reject;
        marker1.src = "images/map_pin.png";
    }).then(function() {
        return animate_pin(marker1, context, point_coord[begin[0]])
    }).then(next_code);

} else {
//... snip
}

function next_code() {
    console.log("In next_code");
    // ... etc
}
```

or, you can move the var next_code above where it is used

```
var next_code = function() {
    console.log("In next_code");
    // ... etc
};

if (first) {
    var pause = true;
    var marker1 = new Image();
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        marker1.onload = resolve;
        marker1.onerror = reject;
        marker1.src = "images/map_pin.png";
    }).then(function() {
        return animate_pin(marker1, context, point_coord[begin[0]])
    }).then(next_code);

} else {
//... snip
}
```

---

You may ask yourself "Why was there no error?"

Because, if you pass anything other than a function as the argument to `.then` - it is silently ignored - this is useful behaviour when chaining Promises, but it makes for interesting WTF moments :p

Comment: Interesting how that works! So this does work to get `next_code` to run, however putting `console.log` before the returning brace of `drawPath`, drawPath is never left. I put `console.log` at the end of all the functions in question and all are reached normally but the one at the end of `drawPath`, which means the code that called `drawPath` isnt continued for some reason

Comment: Update: Actually, the code that called `drawPath` DOES continue, but it uses an empty array because it runs immediately instead of waiting for `drawPath` to finish calling `draw_segments`. On the surface it looks like `drawPath` is called, then the `animate_pin` which splits off into a "thread". The `drawPath` thread is finished while the `animate_pin` thread executes in the right order

Comment: Well you're not waiting for draw path to finish. But you haven't shown the code that calls it and your code doesn't seem to wait on draw segments. Is there any asynchrony in draw segments? If not then you just need to handle the promise returned by draw path correctly

Comment: I wish there was animation code that was synchronous, this would be so much easier. No asynchrony in `draw_segments`, it just calculates points and throws them together with a context like `[context, path]` and puts it into the `arr`. The code that calls `drawPath` is simply `drawPath(source, desti, bool, bool, bool, arr)`. Eventually, when drawPath is finished, `wrap` gets called to actually draw the lines. I think I am going to open a new question to handle this, because it is slightly past what was originally asked here. Hope to see you there, and thank you for the help so far!

Comment: `Eventually, when drawPath is finished` but you don't know when it's finished because you ignore the Promise

Comment: Ignore which promise? `drawpath` doesnt return a promise (though maybe it should)

Comment: see line 4 in my answer? `return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {` - yes, it does return a promise

Comment: I see... for some reason I thought that was used just to allow the `.then()`s to work. So that promise is passed (resolved if successful) back to map.php, which calls `drawPath()`? Thus I can use it in a similar way `drawpath.then()`?

Comment: Yes. Exactly that